# Is the property text-align: center; a good way to center a div using CSS?

Tags: centering, text-align

I need to center a div in relation to its surrounding div container. The div that I want to center contains an ad serving javascript code snippet. Can I use text-align: center to center the div as shown below? Does this conform to W3C standards?

Here is the ad serving javascript:

```
<div id="testadunit" style="text-align: center;">
<!-- below is the ad tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
adxpro_key = "a1300082f3da7cdbc1d61e8399484798";
adxpro_channel = "";
adxpro_code_format = "ads";
adxpro_ads_host = "//adxpro.net";
adxpro_click = "";
adxpro_custom_params = {};
adxpro_width = "180";
adxpro_height = "150";

document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src='"+(location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//adxpro.net\/js/show_ads_adxpro.js'><\/script>");
//]]>
</script>
<!-- End ad tag -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would actualy to use the following css:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Except that older versions of InternetExplorer do not work with "auto", so you'll probably have to keep the text-align:center for those versions of the browser unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` won't center a div unless that div has been set to `inline` or `inline-block`. Your code above won't center the div, but rather the text within the div. @IronWilliamCash has the right answer: Set the left and right margins to auto and the div will be centered within its parent container. I believe setting a div to `inline` or `inline-block` is not supported in older versions of IE either.

As far as W3C standards goes, no idea.